# javascript, how to change timestamp for elements in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, timestamp, element

I have array with this timestamps,

```
var labels = ["2018-12-01T00:00:00.000Z", 
              "2018-12-02T00:00:00.000Z",
              "2018-12-09T00:00:00.000Z", 
              "2018-12-09T00:00:00.000Z",
              "2018-12-18T00:00:00.000Z" 
             ]
```

what is the best way to have array in format 2018-12-01. I need to have date for graph

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and create a new array with the characters you don't want sliced off the end:

```js
var labels = ["2018-12-01T00:00:00.000Z", 
    "2018-12-02T00:00:00.000Z",
    "2018-12-09T00:00:00.000Z", 
    "2018-12-09T00:00:00.000Z",
    "2018-12-18T00:00:00.000Z" 
];

var truncated = labels.map(str => str.slice(0, -14));
console.log(truncated);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [moment](https://momentjs.com/)?

```
function updateTimeFormat(arr) {
  return arr.map(x => {
    return moment(x).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in `Date`, as so:

```
labels.map(label => {
    const date = new Date(label);
    return `${date.getFullYear()}-${date.getMonth()}-${date.getDate()}`;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve what you want by using `Array.prototype.map`

```
var labels = ["2018-12-01T00:00:00.000Z", 
              "2018-12-02T00:00:00.000Z",
              "2018-12-09T00:00:00.000Z", 
              "2018-12-09T00:00:00.000Z",
              "2018-12-18T00:00:00.000Z" 
             ];

const newDates = labels.map( label => {
    const newd = new Date(label);
    const fullYear = newd.getFullYear();
    const month = (newd.getMonth() + 1 ).toString();
    const date = (newd.getDate()).toString();
    return `${fullYear}-${month.length > 1 ? month : month.replace(/^/,0)}-${date.length > 1 ? date : date.replace(/^/,0)}`;
});

console.log(newDates);
```